# Co-related Nested Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery, subquery

Schema:

```
Student (snum: integer, 
         sname: char(30), 
         major: char(25), 
         level: char(2), 
         age: integer)

Faculty (fid: integer, 
         fname: char(30), 
         deptid: integer)

Class (cname: char(40), 
       meets_at: char(20),
       room: char(10), 
       fid: integer | fid    REFS Faculty.fid)

Enrolled (snum: integer, 
          cname: char(40) | snum REFS student.snum, 
          cname REFS class.name)
```

Problem:

P1. Find Name of faculty member, department who taught the maximum number of
distinct classes.

P2. Find Names of all classes and their enrollment strength that have enrollment greater than 5.

My Attempt:

```
#P1:
select distinct f.fname,max(distinct c.cname)
from faculty f,class c
where Exists (select c.fid,max(distinct c.cname) as myCount
from class c where
f.fid=c.fid);

#P2:
select distinct c.cname
from class c
where Exists (select c.cname
from enrolled e where
e.cname=c.cname and count(e.cname)>5);
```

But this is giving me error. Please help me out.

Comment: Which gives you an error? Is it that you get the wrong answer or there's an error parsing the query?

Comment: P1----Wrong Output
P2----Invalid Use of Group Functions

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: `mysql` or `sqlserver` choose one.

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench

Answer (score 0):

**Q #1**: Just do a `group by`

```
select f.fname, COUNT(distinct c.cname)
from faculty f 
join class c
  on f.fid = c.fid
group by f.fname
order by COUNT(distinct c.cname) DESC
limit 1
```

Using correlated query:

Corraleted v1:

```
SELECT *
FROM faculty f
WHERE f.id =  (SELECT c.fid
               FROM class c 
               GROUP BY c.fid
               ORDER BY COUNT(distinct c.cname) DESC
               LIMIT 1)
```

Corraleted v2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT f.*, (SELECT COUNT(distinct c.cname)
                   FROM class c
                   WHERE c.fid = f.id) as total
      FROM faculty f
     ) T
ORDER By Total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I know that Sir! I want to perform this query by using Co-related Nested Query Concept.

Comment: You didnt say that :( Check again. But I dont like that one.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't said before. But I am trying Co-related Nested Query.

Comment: do you have a definition of what co-related nested query is? Because first one look nested, but not co-related.

Comment: Yeah... It is a query that uses values from the outer query. :/

Answer (score 0):

For P2, you can do this with a join, and no nested queries. Doing a condition on an aggregate function is not allowed in the WHERE clause, only in the HAVING clause. You must also group on class names first.

```
SELECT C.name, count(*) as enrollment
FROM Class C INNER JOIN Enrolled E
    ON C.cname=E.cname
GROUP BY C.name
HAVING count(*) > 5;
```

Doing a co-related nested query, try this:

```
SELECT C.cname, count(*) as enrollment_count
FROM Class C INNER JOIN Enrolled E
    ON C.cname = E.cname
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Enrolled E
              WHERE E.cname = C.cname
              GROUP BY E.cname
              HAVING count(*) > 5)
GROUP BY C.cname;
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: I know about this. But I want to do this by using Co-related Nested Query Concept. How can we do that?

Comment: Error. Unknown column C.cname in where clause.

Comment: Forgot you can't do corelation in from clause. Modified it a bit